# Как при загрузке страницы передать куки с помощью JQuery?

Tags: jquery, javascript, cookie

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     b=$.cookie('cookie_name',"value",{path: '/'});
     console.log($.cookie('cookie_name'));
}
```

Ничего не выходит.

P.S. Плагин для работы с куками поставлен верно.

Answer (score 1):

Учтите, что "куки" должны быть переданы браузеру ДО того, как он отобразит контент. По хорошему - до первого html символа, в header'е.

Грубо говоря, тут `$(document).ready();` приносит лишь вред.

Посмотрите примеры на

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/test/tests.js

А `$.cookie('cookie_name',"value",{path: '/'});` попробуйте написать прямо в мета-заголовке страницы, прямо после подключения jQuery.cookie. Должно сработать.